# Android, in same activity go back to previous method called

Tags: java, android

I am coding in Java in Android Studio and I am currently making an Calendar app that save, show, edit events. I had to put some view, like MonthView WeekView and DailyView. At first I made it in a way so all of them were activities and when i want to go back the back pressed button almost done my job. Because of some odds, I turned out to keep only one activity and do the same job with some methods instead of making activities. I have a navigation drawer, so in onItemNavigationClick the user can select which view want. So, my problem is that I cant find a way to act the previous method, like if I go to WeekView and press backButton, get back in Month or in Daily view.

As I see backpressed is to go back an activity, so I think it cant help me. I would apreciate any help.

```
 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuSchedule:
            setAllEvents();
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

            break;
        case R.id.daysView:
            setDaily();
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

            break;

        case R.id.weekView:

            setWeek();
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);


            break;

        case R.id.monthView:
            setMonthView();
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);


            break;
        case R.id.refreshItem:
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
            break;
        case R.id.syncItem:
            break;

        default:
            onNavigationItemSelected(item);
    }


    return true;
}
```

**Example of how my set Methods are working:**

```
 private void setMonthView() {
        monthYearText.setText(monthYearFromDate(CalendarUtils.selectedDate));
        ArrayList<LocalDate> daysInMonth = daysInMonthArray();


        CalendarAdapter calendarAdapter = new CalendarAdapter(daysInMonth, this, getApplicationContext());
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 7);


        calendarRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        calendarRecyclerView.setAdapter(calendarAdapter);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = calendarRecyclerView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height=1500;
        calendarRecyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);

        monthListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        monthYearText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        daysOfWeekDaily.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        daysOfWeek.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        prevMonth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        nextMonth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        calendarRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        nestedScrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }
```

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to David Wesser, the code works in the way I want to, here source code of my problem:

```
 public void onMyBackPressed() {
        // Pop current view type off the stack
        stack.removeFirst();
        // Check the previous view type
        String previousViewType = stack.peekFirst();
        if (previousViewType == null) {
            // Nothing to go back to, so finish this Activity
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }
        if (previousViewType.equals("daily")) {
            setDaily();
        } else if (previousViewType.equals("week")) {
            setWeek();
        } else if (previousViewType.equals("all"))
        {
            setAllEvents();
        }else if (previousViewType.equals("month"))
        {
            setMonthView();
        }
    }




 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menuSchedule:
                setAllEvents();
                stack.addFirst("all");
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

                break;
            case R.id.daysView:
                setDaily();
                stack.addFirst("daily");
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

                break;

            case R.id.weekView:

                setWeek();
                stack.addFirst("week");
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);


                break;

            case R.id.monthView:
                setMonthView();
                stack.addFirst("month");
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);


                break;
            case R.id.refreshItem:
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
                break;
            case R.id.syncItem:
                break;

            default:
                onNavigationItemSelected(item);
        }


        return true;
    }
```

Comment: `setAllEvents();`  , `setDaily();` this all set method is open a fragment ?

Comment: No I dont have any fragments or something, i didn't put the methods here cause i think is unnecessary, these methods parametrize my Main arraylist of calendar and set visibility to specific componets. I want something like go to previous method called.. I dont know how to explain it better

Comment: It is not possible Chirs. Please use fragments for different views

Comment: As I read fragments isnt a good way of making projects, even android studio dont recommend it. I'll wait a little longer if someone has an idea or any other solutions to recommend. Thanks for the interest

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is used for questions/issues regarding the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: ok i did it, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by building a stack that represents the type of view you are showing. Whenever the user selects something from the navigation drawer, you call the method to show that view and you push something on the stack (a `String` or an `Integer` constant) that represents the kind of view you are showing. Then override `onBackPressed()` so that instead of the default behaviour (which is to finish the current `Activity` and return to the previous `Activity`), you so something like this:

- Pop off the last thing from your stack (this represents the currently shown view)
- If there is nothing left on the stack, you should call the default behaviour with `super.onBackPressed()`, which will send the user back to the HOME screen or whatever
- Otherwise, examine the topmost thing on the stack (this represents the previously shown view) and use it to call the appropriate method to show the view that it represents. In this case remember not to push a new thing onto the stack because the top item on the stack already represents the view that is being shown.

---

Code Example:

```
// Declare the stack as a member variable in the Activity
ArrayDeque<String> stack = new ArrayDeque<String>();
```

inside your `switch` statement, something like this for each different view type:

```
case R.id.daysView:
        setDaily();
        // push the current view type onto the stack
        stack.addFirst("day");
case R.id.weekView:
        setWeek();
        // push the current view type onto the stack
        stack.addFirst("week");
etc...
```

Now override the behaviour of `onBackPressed()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Pop current view type off the stack
    stack.removeFirst();
    // Check the previous view type
    String previousViewType = stack.peekFirst();
    if (previousViewType == null) {
        // Nothing to go back to, so finish this Activity
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }
    if (previousViewType.equals("day")) {
        setDaily();
    } else if (previousViewType.equals("week")) {
        setWeekly();
    } else ... // rest of the view types here
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I can fully understand what you are saying... I have only one activity with these views, so the backpressed cant go to other activity. I want to get the previous action made.. for example I press the button Daily View and then the button WeekView.. I want in backpressed the function represents DailyView to called off

Comment: Yes, I know that. That's why you override `onBackPressed()` so that it doesn't go back to the previous `Activity`. Instead, it just calls the method to change the view contents. You would only go back to the previous `Activity` (or end the app), if the stack is empty (ie: there is no previous view to show the user).

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, I dont know yet how to build a stack, but I will search the way you approch my problem, do you have some lines of the code to understand your approch maybe?

Comment: Added some code. I didn't compile this, just out of my head, but hopefully you get the idea. Should work ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll do some work and I'll update the post when it's accomplished

Comment: Thank you very much, this task made me struggle for 2weeks now, your answer was 100% right!!